# std::string prints characters beyond limit when used as array

Tags: c++

Programming: Practices and Principles - Bjarne Stroustrup

Drill in Ch 5 - Errors

```
string s = "Success!\n";
for(int i=0;i<100;++i)
    cout<<s[i];
```

This prints random characters with several spaces in between after printing Success! beyond the actual string limit. Why is that? Why is it not throwing an out_of_bounds exception?

Comment: Because there is nothing that says there should be an out_of_bounds exception.

Comment: If you want bounds-checking and exceptions thrown, then use [`std::string::at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike Java and similar languages, the standard doesn't dictate that an exception should be thrown when an array is indexed outside of its defined bounds. Doing so causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Not checking if an index is within an array's bounds makes for fast indexing, but it means you have to do some extra bookkeeping.

Luckily, `std::string` does this bookkeeping for you by storing a character array's size. If you need to use bounds checking at runtime, use `std::string::at()`.

Edit: As said in the comments, it's almost always a bug if you are using `at()` just to catch the exception thrown. Exceptions should be used for problems that leave your application in an unusual state. You should write code with the mindset that an index out of bounds should never happen. It's best to make sure that none of your indices are out of bounds before passing them to `string::operator[]` instead of using `string::at()`, which is a sort of crutch.

Comment: The first sentence is imprecise almost to the point of meaninglessness, as C++ doesn't throw any exceptions at all.    It is code statements and functions that throw exceptions, not the language.   In this case, it is `string`'s array indexing that doesn't do range checking or throwing exceptions (and its `at()` member function which does).

Comment: @Peter I adjusted the wording; however, I'm not sure it added anything crucial to the answer.

Comment: What's missing in this answer is that using `at()` is almost always wrong, because an index-out-of-bounds error in a string is a bug, not an unusual but valid run-time state of your program (which is what exceptions represent in C++). When your code has gone to the point of producing a wrong index to be used for something as low-level as a `std::string`, then a lot of higher-level layers of the code have already shown erroneous behaviour. A problem like this is not fixed with a `catch` but with an editor and a compiler.

Comment: @ChristianHackl ........ What should I DO? O_O Should I or should I not use at()? Or am I at such a noob level that I don't need to worry about bounds checking in `std::string`?

Comment: @Andy356: It's hard to explain in a short comment like this. No, you should not use `at()`. Not because bounds checking is bad but because an exception being thrown is the wrong way to deal with an error like this. Use `[]` and ensure within your own code that all indices are correct. For a very simple example, consider a program which asks the user to enter a number N which shall serve as index into the string "test". The program prints the N-th character of "test". Detecting a potential index-out-of-bounds condition here would be the responsibility of your own code.

Comment: @Andy356: In other words, you would not blindly call `s.at(user_input)` and catch the exception. You would first have something like `if (!user_input < s.size() { printError(); }`. Invalid user input is (typically) completely normal and not an exceptional program state.

Comment: So I should deal with user input like I normally do with `while` and `if`?

Comment: @Andy356 Deal with user input however the situation requires. If you need to check an input that is out of bounds, it's probably best to do that with conditional statements like `while` and `if`.